# How to use mysql with Regex replace select name from table as t and t.name like A and t.name like B and t.name like c

Tags: mysql, regex

I need find results from table "x" and x.name must have "zhongwen", 'yingwen', 'riwen' three word  but not one of them,and i must use MySQL with regex, what can I do? (my English is so weak,sorry)

Query I tried:

```
select pv.name 
from pvideo as pv 
where  pv.name like '%zhongwen%' and pv.name like '%yingwen%' and pv.name like '%riwen%' 
limit 1000
```

Comment: If your query works, why do you need regex?

Comment: `but not one of them` <-- what does this requirement mean?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I suppose **not** `pv.name like '%zhongwen%' OR pv.name like '%yingwen%' OR pv.name like '%riwen%'` (notice the `OR`)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I mean that three word must exist at the same time.

Comment: @Cid Yes ,you are right

Comment: @PaulSpiegel beacuse  there are maybe three 'like ' or more 'like' i should use, this sql just a example

Comment: Regex will not make things simpler in this case. At least I never heard of a rule "every of (X|Y|Z)". You either just use what you have, or try it with a full-text index.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel maybe you are right, i search one online a day,but i can't found any sql with regex can solve my problem.

Comment: I can't prove it - But I think it's not possible without writing down all possible permutations like `'.*(zhongwen.*yingwen.*riwen|zhongwen.*riwen.*yingwen|yingwen.*zhongwen.*riwen|yingwen.*riwen.*zhongwen|riwen.*yingwen.*zhongwen|riwen.*zhongwen.*yingwen).*'` - That's **only** for three search terms.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thank you anyway,Maybe i should look at other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Your `AND` is checking for all 3 names to be in the same row.  If you want to check for _any_ of the 3 names to be in a row, use `OR`.

Comment: Why "must" you use regexp?  Is this homework?  Think about `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` -- there are lots of examples of that.